# c# new field and foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, field

I've crated a new field called `cerveny` & `cerny` with some numbers.
But I'm getting a problem when I try to do `foreach`. I foud function `foreach` just a few days ago so I don't know how it correctly works.
Someone knows why I'm getting this error?

```
not all code paths return a value
```

Thanks so much.

Field:

```
int[] cerveny = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36 };
int[] cerny = new int[] { 2,4,6,8,10,11,13,15,17,20,22,24,26,28,29,31,33,35 };
```

variables

```
Credit = 0;
vyhry = 0;
Sazka = 0;
Vyhra = 0;
sazky = new ArrayList();
```

And thats the for each

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int Cislo = rnd.Next(0, 36);
Vyhra = 0;
foreach (string[] pole in sazky)
{
    if (pole[0] == Cislo.ToString())
    {
        Vyhra += Convert.ToInt32(pole[1]) * 36;
    }
    if (pole[0] == "licha" && Cislo % 2 == 1)
    {
        Vyhra += Convert.ToInt32(pole[1]) * 2;
    }
    if (pole[0] == "suda" && Cislo % 2 == 0)
    {
        Vyhra += Convert.ToInt32(pole[1]) * 2;
    }
    if (pole[0] == "cervena")
    {
        foreach (int policko in cerveny)
        {
            if (pole[0] == Cislo.ToString())
            {
                Vyhra += Convert.ToInt32(pole[1]) * 2;
            }
        }
        if (pole[0] == "cerna")
        {
            foreach (int policko in cerny)
            {
                if (pole[0] == Cislo.ToString())
                {
                    Vyhra += Convert.ToInt32(pole[1]) * 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    vyhry += Vyhra;
    sazky.Clear();
    Sazka = 0;
    Credit += Vyhra;
    return Cislo;
}
```

Comment: You need to edit this so that that code can be put into an IDE to see. But anyway, the reason is that your `return` is inside your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the `Not all code paths return a value` error: ensure your function `return` a value even if `sazky` is empty

Answer (score 4):

"Not all code paths return a value" is not an foreach error. It just means that you have a function that is supposed to return a value, but there is a way for the code to leave that function without a return value. That is an error. You did not post the function itself, but make sure that whatever happens, and whatever conditions are met, the function will end in a return statement.

I think your return is *inside* the foreach. If your collection has no elements, the foreach will not run once and the return statement will not be reached. Check your braces if you really meant to put the return statement where it is now.

Comment: Thanks ;-) now i nderstand it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

sazky is `ArrayList`. It is the collection of `object`. For example:

```
foreach (object _pole in sazky)
{
    string[] pole = (string[])_pole;
    ......
```

And I recommend to use [System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19)